# Problema com CSS no Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, resolução-de-tela, zoom

Olá, estou com um projeto em Angular (2 e 4) e Materialize + Material Angular. O problema é que, não consigo aplicar a propriedade CSS **zoom**. Onde no Chrome está tudo ok mas no Firefox ele não possui essa propriedade. **Qual alternativa posso usar neste caso?**

**No Firefox está assim:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**No Chrome fica com o mesmo bug porém, se eu aplico um zoom de 80%, ele ajusta:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Exemplo do código CSS usado para ajustar no Chrome:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1366px) {
  html {
    zoom: 80%;
  }
}
```

**Tentei usar o ***transform: scale*** porém não resolveu (deu margin nos 4 cantos), veja:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Cara nesse caso te sugiro colocar o código HTML/CSS referente a esse problema. Da uma limpada nos arquivos e posta aqui apenas os código dessa barra que está buggando. Pq fica difícil te dar uma resposta precisa assim. Tb reparei que vc está querendo diminuir o HTML inteiro só para ajustar a margem é isso? Se for isso é muito errado pode te dar problemas de responsividade sérios no futuro. Se possível poste o código como falei

Comment: Olá, tudo bem? Então, eu consegui resolver com o '@media' mas usando ele dentro de "@supports (display: flex)". Muito obrigado!

Comment: Boa, vc fez do jeito certo com o @supports! Meio estranho esse bug mas que bom que resolveu. Vc pode posta uma resposta mais completa para sua própria pergunta e depois marca-la como aceita. Assim essa pergunta não fica aberta no sistema mesmo já tendo sido resolvida!